# Retrieving data from database

Tags: android, sql, database

I am trying to retrieve data from a database and I am using code that I found on blogs with some changes.

This is my php file:

```
<?php

  mysql_connect("host","username","password");

  mysql_select_db("peopledata");

  $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE birthyear>'".$_REQUEST['year']."'");

  while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))

          $output[]=$e;

       print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();?>
```

I have created the following database:

```
      CREATE TABLE people (

  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,

  name VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,

  sex BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',

  birthyear INT NOT NULL

  )
```

And this is my code in my Android Java application:

```
public class SnowReportActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setImageClickListener();

}

private void setImageClickListener() {
    ImageView map_image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.map_icon);
    map_image.setOnTouchListener(new ImageView.OnTouchListener() {
    //OnTouchListener listener = new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(!(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN))
                return false; //If the touch event was not putting the finger down on the screen, return false(Actions may be move, up, and so on)
            final float x = event.getX();
            final float y = event.getY();
            //System.out.println("Coordinates of button pressed are: X is %d"+x+" and Y is %d"+ y);
            if(x and y in some range)
                DoFirst();
            //... and so on...
            //In the end, you must return a boolean saying whether you "consumed" the event - if you handled the event or not.
           return true;
        }

});

}
@SuppressWarnings("null")
private void DoFirst() {
    Log.d("SnowReportApp","Do first thing");
    setContentView(R.layout.parnassos);
    String result = "";
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb=null;
    //the year data to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year","1980"));

    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example/httpdocs/getAllPeopleBornAfter.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
    //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();

            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    //parse JSON data
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                            ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
                            ", sex: "+json_data.getInt("sex")+
                            ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("birthyear")
                    );
            }

    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

} }
```

The database is created on a server of my webpage. I haven't given the url, but instead I have written example.com. The problem is that in my logcat I see the html code of my whole website and an extra warning:

> Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 2 of

---

When my server is on my site I get my whole html code because I do not provide on my code the username and password required from my server. The httppost takes as argument only the URL. If my server is on my local machine then by just giving the ip address of the machine I see the correct results. Can anyone help me on how to provide the username and password?

Comment: The error that you are getting means that the JSON string which you are getting in the  JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting means that the JSON string which you are getting in the  `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);`,the result string is not a valid Json arrray.Just check what comes in the result object

Comment: And what about seeing in logcat the whole html file of my webpage?

Comment: So you mean your web page is created with the help of JSONObject and still you get the error as you stated ?

Comment: Maybe i didn't understand how to fix this out. Can you suggest me any changes on my code?

Comment: Can you share what you are getting in the result parameter. I need to see the JSON response.

Comment: I did the following change: instead of  JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);   I wrote this: JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result); The result is defined former on the code as result=sb.toString();

Comment: Ohh i also dint realize that :) You need to take the String as part of JSONONbect first and then get array from that .. So did it finally work ?

Comment: No I am getting again the same warning and my whole html page being printed.